# How to implement an INPC for referencing a static property?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

There is a static configuration class:

```
public class Cfg : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private static string _niceString;

    public static string NiceString {
        get => _niceString;
        set {
            _niceString = value;
            NotifyStaticPropertyChanged("NiceString");
        }
    }

    public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;
    private static void NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

If we make a binding like this: `Content="{Binding Path=(local:Сfg.Nice)}"` Everything will work.

However, if I make the following property in the VM:

```
 public string MyBestString => Cfg.NiceString;
```

So *(class implements INPC using KindOfMagic, which works)* and implement the binding like this: `Content="{Binding MyBestString}" then nothing will work.

Why? And how to make it work?

---

P.S. It's just impossible to use such a binding `Content =" {Binding Path = (local: Сfg.Nice)} "` - I need to process the values before displaying them in the element.

Comment: The VM has to raise PropertyChanged whenever the value of `MyBestString` changes. The Binding has no way of guessing that it's supposed to find this static object somewhere; all it knows about is what you gave it. So have your viewmodel add a handler to `Cfg.PropertyChanged`, and have the handler call `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyBestString));` whenever `Cfg` raises a change notification for `Nice`.

Comment: *" I need to process the values before displaying them in the element."* -- that sounds like a value converter

Comment: Yes you are right. Write answer by yourself? And at the expense of the converter - I don’t like to write them at every step, it’s easier for me to change `get`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason that the original property cannot serve the notification change event for `MyBestString` as well.

Change your code to such:

```
   public static string NiceString {
        get => _niceString;
        set {
            _niceString = value;
            NotifyStaticPropertyChanged("NiceString");
            NotifyStaticPropertyChanged("MyBestString");
        }
    }
```